# Using Moxy with Jersey 2 on a Apache Tomcat 8.0.36

Tags: tomcat, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, moxy

Hi I'm trying to use process JSON using Moxy and Jersey 2, my understanding is that Moxy is auto-discoverable by Jersey as long as it is on the class path which it should be as i've set a dependency in my pom.xml , i've also tried registering Moxy manually with no success.

When trying to access the resource at("localhost:8080/Test/hello") an HTTP Status 404 - Not Found is produced by the browser.

The following warnings are produced in the eclipse console when the resources is being accessed.

Warnings (WARNING: Error parsing media type 'MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON')

(WARNING: A provider HelloRest registered in SERVER runtime does not implement any provider interfaces applicable in the SERVER runtime. Due to constraint configuration problems the provider HelloRest will be ignored.)

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.    0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>asm</groupId>
      <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.23.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
         <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
           <version>2.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
   </project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.    org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
    <param-value>ResourceLoader</param-value>
    </init-param>
   </servlet>
</web-app>
```

ResourceLoader.java

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class ResourceLoader extends Application//ResourceConfig 
{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() 
    {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        // register root resource
        classes.add(HelloRest.class);

        return classes;
    }
    /*
    public ResourceLoader() 
    {       
        packages("src");
    }*/

}
```

HelloRest.java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloRest 
{
  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Event message()
  {
  System.out.println("Hey");
  Event event = new Event(1,"Terry","Edinburgh");
    return event;
  }
}
```

Event.java

```
public class Event
{
  private int id;
  private String name;
  private String location;
  public Event(){}
  public Event(int id,String name, String location)
  {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
  }
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getLocation() {
    return location;
  }
  public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` declaration from your `web.xml`.

Comment: I tried this but it produced a "workspace/Test/target/m2e-wtp/web-resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (No such file or directory)" error. I unchecked Maven Archiver generates files under the build directory in Java EE Intergration  preferences page which removed the new error but the initial problem was still produced.

Comment: Post the full stack trace.

Comment: Ok actually since removing the "org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer" I have a completely new error  a SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Test] in context with path [/Test] threw exception [java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.writeTo(MOXyJsonProvider.java:944)